# Java class and package name manipulation

Tags: java, api, parsing, package

Is there any API, preferably part of J2SE (but willing to consider alternatives) that allows manipulation and parsing of Java class names?

For example, given a `String` representing a class name (such as that which would be passed to a `ClassLoader`, an API to extract the package name from a class name, extract any inner class name if present, etc?

I can't create `Class` objects from the Strings and then use reflective methods, since this is all happening before any Class is created - this code needs to parse the strings to decide how to create the `Class` in the first place.  So the API needs to work on `String`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this because it's been a while and I don't anticipate any new answers: I don't believe there is any API in J2SE that lets you parse string class names.  It's not too hard to write you your own, and things like package name formats are defined in the language spec and not likely to change (i.e,. they aren't going to start using something other than periods to delimit package names).

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of methods in [`java.lang.Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) which you can work with:

```
Class inner     = Class.forName("my.package.TopLevel$Inner");
Class topLevel = inner.getDeclaringClass();
Class[] allInner = topLevel.getDeclaredClasses();

Class anonymous = Class.forName("my.package.TopLevel$Inner$2");
Class stringArray  = Class.forName("[Ljava.lang.String;");    

Package pkg = topLevel.getPackage();
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear - I have Strings representing class names and I want to parse these, as part of implementing (for example) a ClassLoader.  So I definitely don't have Class objects.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what your describing is what is commonly known as "Reflection".

- [java.lang.reflect API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)
- [more, general/tutorial stuff](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-1997/jw-09-indepth.html) related to the Reflection API

Comment: See my comment immediately above to Michael Brewer-Davis' reply.